# urlpatterns return the value of very first function

Tags: python, django

I just started to learn Python Django Webpage development. My plan was to show the current time and window service status in my page.

I have two functions in my views.py and urlpatterns refers these two functions in urls.py
Whenever i run the server, the very first url only showed in my page.

## views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import psutil, datetime

def winservice(request):
    servicename = psutil.win_service_get('BrokerAgent')
    service = servicename.as_dict()
    if service['status'] == 'running':
        return HttpResponse("<h2>Hey Citrix is Up and Running .. </h2>")        


def current_datetime(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    html = "<html><body>It is now %s.</body></html>" % now
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

## urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url


from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.current_datetime, name ='current_datetime'),
    url(r'^winservice$',views.winservice,name ='winservice'),    
    ]
```

Expected Result:
Page should contains
Current time.
Status of my service.

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you go to `/` you will see the datetime. If you go to `/winservice` you will see the Citrix message. What are you asking?

Comment: You `/winservice` may not return any response because service is not running, since you don't return anything in that case

Comment: Apologies.
My urls.py is
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.current_datetime, name ='current_datetime'),
    url(r'^$',views.winservice,name ='winservice'),    
    ]

I want to show the both results in a same page.

My code will show me only date and time. If i comment current_datetime view,  page will display the status of Citrix. 
My Page url:
http://localhost:8000/winservicetest

Comment: You can't have two views on the same page. One URL pattern maps to one view.

Comment: Thanks @DanielRoseman